# 1adding object constraints to 2 animation

Tags: constraints

I have a dish attached to the one end of a bar. when the bar pivots up and down on the Z axis, the dish with copy location on, remains horizontal. Which is what i want
at the end of the bar, I parent it to a circle lying flat. so that when i rotate the circle on the Z at 360, the bar will swing around like a clock hand. which is what i want
But the problem here is the dish also rotates on the z. how do i prevent it from rotating?
[image]

Comment: This sort of thing?  Link - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtkhCKZLZs_Pg2u9qnHe4x6CJz6x?e=R61TCF

Comment: Yes, Thank you @Edgel3D.
 I notice that the bar is under the dish. I had mine at the side. Will go work on it.

Comment: You can slide the dish anywhere you want.  Just parent it to an end vertice on the shaft (cube) so it won't want to rotate or tip.